# How to delete class as this and set it as null in c++

Tags: c++

So, I have an array of a class called "`Customer`"

```
Customer** customersarray[] = new Customer*[customer];
```

I'm receiving int customer with `cin`.

anyways, in *customer.cpp*, there is a method called `void deactivate()`.

which goes like this:

```
void Custmoer::deactivate() 
{
    if (this != NULL)
        remove this;
    //this = NULL; I want to do this but it doesn't work.
}
```

and the purpose of this is to remove it from customer array when satisfies a certain condition. So for example,

```
for (int i = customer - 1; i >= 0; i--) 
{
    if (customersarray[i]->getAngerLevel() == 5) {
        customersarray[i]->deactivate();
    }

    for (int z = i; i < customer - 1; i++) {
        *(customersarray + z) = *(customersarray + z + 1);
    }
    customer--;
}
```

so my first questions are:

1. why does `this = NULL` not work?
2. is there a simpler way to remove something from pointer array when a condition is satisfied? (for example, remove all customers that has anger level of 5.)

Comment: `remove this;` Huh??

Comment: Is there a simpler way? Yes of course, forget it's a pointer and remove it from the array in the same way that you would remove *anything* from an array. Pointers are not special

Comment: BTW `Customer** customersarray[] = new Customer*[customer];` is not legal code, I guess you meant `Customer** customersarray = new Customer*[customer];`

Comment: You may also want to have a look at [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead of using raw pointers for arrays.

Comment: Looks like the OP wants to use a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Customer>>` actually, @TrebuchetMS

Comment: (1)  Within a non-static member function, `this` cannot be assigned.   Outside a non-static member function `this` does not exist.   In C++11 and later, `this` is a prvalue, one property of which is that it cannot be on the left hand side of an assignment.   (2)   A simpler approach in C++ is to use the standard algorithm `remove()` or `remove_if()`.

Answer (score 2):

Your mistake is thinking that you can remove something from a `Customer*` array by some magic inside the `Customer` class, but that's not true. Just remove a customer from the customer array where ever the customer array is. For instance using remove_if

```
#include <algorithm>

Customer** customersarray = new Customer*[customer];
...
customer = std::remove_if(customersarray, customersarray + customer,
    [](Customer* c) { return c->anger() == 5; }) - customersarray;
```

This updates the `customer` variable to be the new size of the array, but doesn't free or reallocate any memory. Since you are using dynamic arrays and pointers you are responsible for that.

Which is why you should really not be using pointers or arrays, but using vectors instead.

```
std::vector<Customer> customerVector;
```

Life will be so much simpler.

Comment: Would `std::remove_if()` actually work with a raw array?

Comment: Yes, but you'd need to track the size, I'll update my post.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: @황현빈 You shouldn't struggle with raw pointers, raw arrays or manual `new`/`delete`. Take the advice given and use the appropriate classes and functions from the standard [Containers library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) and/or [Dynamic memory management](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory) if you ever want to write production ready code in c++.

Answer (score 0):

1. Type of "this" is a constant pointer which means you cant change where it points
2. Your function can return a boolean and if its true just set your pointer to null

Comment: _"Your function can return a boolean and if its true just set your pointer to null"_?? Only setting the pointer to `NULL` would cause memory leaks. Also what criteria should be used to determine if `true` or `false` should be returned?

Comment: I assumed he would delete the memory in deactivate method(if he changes remove this to delete this). Also I suggested to add a return value to deactivate method to know whether or not he deleted the object so he can set pointer in array to null

Comment: `delete this;` isn't forbidden (and in fact used in e.g. Qt), but extremely unusual; especially since there are way simpler and more robust solutions for the OPs problem.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, attending to *[RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_acquisition_is_initialization)* idiom, you are trying to delete an object before using its destructor `~Customer()`. You should try to improve the design of your `Customer` class through a smart use of constructor and destructor:

```
Customer() {// initialize resources}
~Customer() {// 'delete' resources previously created with 'new'}
void deactivate() {// other internal operations to be done before removing a customer}
```

Then, your constructor `Customer()` would initialize your internal class members and the destructor `~Customer()` would release them if necessary, avoiding memory leaks.

The other question is, why do you not use another type of Standard Container as `std::list<Customer>`? It supports constant time removal of elements at any position:

```
std::list<Customer> customers
...
customers.remove_if([](Customer foo) { return foo.getAngerLevel() == 5; });
```

If you only expect to erase `Customer` instances once during the lifetime of the program the idea of using a `std::vector<Customer>` is also correct.

Answer (score 0):

You'll be much better off using a `std::vector`, all memory memory management gets much safer. You cannot modify the this pointer, but that would be meaningless anyway:

1. It is a local variable, so any other pointer outside would not be changed, not even the one you called the function on (`x->f()`: the value of x is *copied* into `this`).
2. It contains the address of the current object - the current object is at a specific memory location and cannot be moved away from (not to be mixed up with 'moving' in the context of move semantics!).

You *can*, however, delete the current object (but I don't say you *should*!!!):

```
class Customer
{
    static std::vector<Customer*> customers;
public:
    void commitSuicide()
    {
        auto i = customers.find(this);
        if(i != customers.end())
            customers.erase(i);
        delete this;
    }
}
```

Might look strange, but is legal. But it is dangerous as well. You need to be absolutely sure that you do not use the `this` pointer or any other poiner to the current object any more afterwards (accessing non-static members, calling non-static functions, etc), it would be undefined behaviour!

```
x->commitSuicide();
x->someFunction(); // invalid, undefined behaviour!!! (x is not alive any more)
```

Similar scenario:

```
class Customer
{
    static std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Customer>> customers;
public:
    void commitSuicide()
    {
        auto i = customers.find(this);
        if(i != customers.end())
        {
            customers.erase(i); // even now, this is deleted!!! (smart pointer!)
            this->someFunction(); // UNDEFINED BEHAVIOUR!
        }
    }
}
```

If handling it correctly, it works, sure. Your scenario might allow a much safer pattern, though:

```
class Customer
{
    static std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Customer>> customers;
public:
    Customer()
    {
        customers->push_back(this);
    };
    ~Customer()
    {
        auto i = customers.find(this);
        if(i != customers.end())
            customers.erase(i);
    }
}
```

There are numerous variations possible (some including smart pointers); which one is most appropriate depends on the use case, though...